# 1 struct, 3 Protocols, and 1 func to call them all

Tags: swift, polymorphism, protocols

I am pretty sure this is only possible with classes, but wasn't sure if it's possible to do the following with structs:

```
protocol Pro {
    var x: Int {get set}
    mutating func foo()
}

protocol Pro2: Pro {
    var y: Int {get set}
}

protocol Pro3: Pro {
    var z: Int {get set}
}


extension Pro2 {
    mutating func foo() {y *= 2}
}

extension Pro3 {
    mutating func foo() {z += 2}
}


struct Aye: Pro2, Pro3 {
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
    var z: Int = 0

    mutating func foo() {
        // call foo() from Pro2 and Pro3
    }
}
```

I want the struct to call both the `foo()` calls from `Pro2` and `Pro3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not currently,** since

- (as you probably already know) you need to implement `Aye#foo` with *something* since there are multiple default implementations with the same signature.
- you cannot call `self.foo` within the implementation without causing infinite recursion, no matter how much casting you try.
- the implementation in the struct will *always* be called instead of the default implement, so it is impossible to do any fancy casting at the call site.

I say "not currently" because I am not sure if this behavior is by design. As you said, this is no problem for classes.

(I had another answer, which was way off-base. Thanks [@appzYourLife](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761687/appzyourlife) for correcting it.)

Comment: That's exactly what I thinking. But I didn't know if there was some protocol extension using `where` trick that I wasn't aware of.